# AWS EKS - Get available Kubernetes versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am looking for a programmatic way to get available Kubernetes versions in AWS EKS. Something similar to the following Azure CLI command:

```
az aks get-versions --location eastus --output table
```

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I'm not completely sure but I don't think one exists. It's in the docs though so you could parse those.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I already had a look at the docs but I found no AWS CLI command neither eksctl command to retrieve the Kubernetes versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, there is no API that explicitly returns the list of available Kubernetes versions available in AWS EKS.
However, there is a somewhat hacky way to get this by describing all add-on versions available and getting the K8s versions they are compatible with.

I guess it would be a fair assumption that all available K8s versions in EKS would be compatible with some add-on or the other. In which case, the below CLI command will return the list of available Kubernetes versions present in EKS which can be used.

```
aws eks describe-addon-versions | jq -r ".addons[] | .addonVersions[] | .compatibilities[] | .clusterVersion" | sort | uniq
```

The command gets all Add-ons for EKS and each Add-ones compatible version and then uses jq utility to get the unique Kubernetes versions.

Comment: That is an ingenious hack!   and it works.  Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```bash
eksctl version -o json | jq -r '.EKSServerSupportedVersions[]'
```

The versions are those supported at the moment the `eksctl` tool is built.

Better than describing addons in the sense that it's not necessary to authenticate with AWS. Worse in the sense that one has to keep ones `eksctl` up to date.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but you can describe all the addons and select one that you need.
For example I need the aws-ebs-csi-driver do I use the following command

`aws eks describe-addon-versions --addon-name aws-ebs-csi-driver --query "addons[0].addonVersions[0].compatibilities[0].clusterVersion" --output text`

In fact you can choose the addon you want or all the addons (not recommendend):

`aws eks describe-addon-versions --query "addons[0].addonVersions[0].compatibilities[0].clusterVersion" --output text`

This will output the latest version for the first addon in the alphabetic order

See [related AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/describe-addon-versions.html) for further informations.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
aws eks describe-cluster --name CLUSTER_NAME --region eu-west-2 --query 'cluster.version'
```

Comment: That shows the current version of a specific cluster.

Comment: gotcha, did you check passing a dummy value in the aws eks create cluster cli to see whether the api exposes the available versions as an error message?